# How to get a list from query in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

when I do the following in python using sqlalchemy

`someVar = self.session.query(sometable.someVar).group_by(sometable.someVar).all()`

I get a list of one variable tuples like

`[(var1,), (var2,), ..]`

Is there a way of getting a flat list within sqlalchemy.
I know how to flatten the list of tuple within python code, but that solution is bit clumsy.
I am just wondering if this is possible.
My goal is to get a list of distinct entries someVar from sometable.

Comment: How is following flattening clumsy? `someVarFlat = [var[0] for var in someVar]`?  And No, there is no way to do this in sqlalchemy query directly.

Comment: van, I did that. It's not real clumsy, but I was wondering if it were possible to do it within alchemy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use (in @classmethod - that's why cls instance here; I also have added 'session' to class properties=)

```
list(session.query(cls))
```

returns exactly the simple list of all DeclarativeBase's instances.

Comment: I think your trouble is because of *group_by* method. I use pythonic mechanism of filter the sequences with filter() function instead of integrated in the SqlAlchemy one. It's not very efficient, but I do so because of some backward-compatibility reasons. And here it seems to be reasonable approach.